# Kafka consumer: fetching topic metadata for topics from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:user-Desktop,port:9092)] failed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, producer-consumer

Tried to run Kafka producer in one machine and consumer in another machine.
Set the following properties:
advertised.host.name
advertised.port

But getting the following error on console consumer:

> bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper ip:2181 --topic topic
>   --from-beginning

```
[2016-01-18 16:38:00,939] WARN Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 2112 for topics [Set(topic)] from broker [id:0,host:user-Desktop,port:9092] failed (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:93)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:66)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:60)
[2016-01-18 16:38:00,939] WARN [console-consumer-82496_gopikrishnan-B85M-D3H-A-1453114849146-e6661d41-leader-finder-thread], Failed to find leader for Set([topic,0]) (kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread)
kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(topic)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:user-Desktop,port:9092)] failed
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:72)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:93)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:66)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:60)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
    ... 3 more
```

What has to be done to fix the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding host address in etc/hosts fixed the issue.

Comment: you made my day.Thanks

Comment: Genius solution!